# Lighthouse: Ensure text remains visible during loading MaterialDesignIcons Webfonts

Tags: css, vuetify.js, display, lighthouse, material-design-icons

I want to improve [Google Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) score of a web application built using [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/).

To increase the performance score, I have been trying to get rid of the diagnostics:

> Ensure text remains visible during webfont load
>
> Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading. [Learn more](https://web.dev/font-display?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=extension)
>
> URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.95 (cdn.jsdelivr.net)

This outcome was also for installing `Roboto` through https://fonts.googleapis.com , and it disappeared when I added `display=swap` to the links as follows:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
<link 
  rel="preload" 
  as="style" 
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap" 
  crossorigin>
<link 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap" 
  crossorigin>
```

However, apparently, it **does not make any difference** to add `display=swap` to [MaterialDesignIcons css file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css) like:

```
<link 
  rel="preload"
  as="style"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css?display=swap"
  crossorigin>
<link 
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css?display=swap"
  crossorigin>
```

Doing so, the diagnostics item does not vanish. How should I load `materialdesignicons.min.css` so that *the text remains visible during webfont load*?

Comment: Your best option would be to use [@mdi/js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/js) so you aren't using a font for icons. [Vuetify now supports this natively](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/js).

Comment: At first I doubted if it'd bring significant overhead to the bundle size, but apparently it can perform tree-shaking. Worths a try, thanks.

Comment: @JamesCoyle does that mean it is recommended to use svg rather than fonts for icons? I'm considering to install @mdi/svg to use it in php (since I use a static website generator anyway).

Comment: Yes SVG is a better option as you are only serving the required icons rather than the full set every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Material icons font is also available from https://fonts.google.com/icons